# Link-time optimizations in CUDA 11 - what are they and how to use them?

Tags: cuda, compiler-optimization, nvcc, compiler-options, lto

The CUDA 11 [features announcement](https://news.developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-toolkit/), it's said that there are now:

> New link time optimization capabilities

what link-time optimizations does nvcc actually employ (e.g. relative to the LTO capabilities in host-side code with g++ or clang++)?

Also - is there something one needs to do to get LTO enabled, or does it always occur (unlike with host-side code where you need to compile with an `-flto` switch?

Comment: I haven't explored that new feature yet, but would *assume* that function inlining across compilation units is one of those capabilities. Should be easy enough to confirm or refute with a simple experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

To enable link-time optimization, use `--dlink-time-opt` (or  `dlto`) when invoking the NVCC compiler, both for compilation and for device-side code linking. No (link-time) optimization will be applied if the compiler can't find the relevant intermediate information.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that -dlto has to be with compile time and link time, if you link your program using non-nvcc, such as gcc or g++, then you may not get the best performance

Comment: I already said that.